# why is this find method returning None and throwing error?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

def tableData(data, attrs):
    row = []
    
    data = data.find(attrs=attrs)
    tr = data.find_all('tr')
    header = [ th.get_text(strip=True) for th in data.find_all('th') ]
    if header:
        row.append(header)
    for tr in tr[1:]:
        row.append([ td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all('td')])
    return row

url1 = 'https://www.nfl.com/standings/league/2019/REG'
page1 = requests.get(url1)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1.text, 'lxml')
table = soup1.find('table', attrs={'summary': 'Standings - Detailed View'})
# print(table)
print(tableData(table, {'summary': 'Standings - Detailed View'}))
```

even in the debugger i see the value of data to contain **Standings - Detailed View** but when `data.find(attrs=attrs)` is run it seems to return None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the table: `table`. It has rows and everything, but it does NOT have any further "Standings - Detailed View" attributes. Proceed straight to the rows:

```
def tableData(data):#, attrs):
    row = []    
    #data = data.find(attrs=attrs)
    tr = data.find_all('tr')
```

Better yet, use pandas (since you import it, anyway) to extract the table as a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.nfl.com/standings/league/2019/REG')[0]
```